# Splitting a list of tuples and converting datatype

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have the following lists in python:

```
list1 = '(MINNESOTA, 8), (BEDFORD, 3)'

list2 = '(NEW JERSEY, 1), (NEW YORK, 1), (SAVANNAH, 1)'
```

I would like to consider each tuple as an element in the list. Then I would like to convert the 1st element in the tuple to a string and the second to an integer.

From there I would like to consider only the tuple with the maximum integer in the list and return the string. In the case of list 2 where there is no definite max, I would like to return all strings.

```
list1 output: MINNESOTA

list2 output: NEW JERSEY, NEW YORK, SAVANNAH
```

Comment: Those aren't lists, those are strings.

Comment: What code have you written so far to address this problem?